# How to install transmission bittorrent client busybox function

Tags: embedded-linux, bittorrent, busybox, buildroot

I found my WD MyPassport Wireless is running Buildroot Linaro linux with busybox; It doesn't have aptitude package manager. I don't know much about busybox; I came to know the commands provided by the busybox are called defined functions. How can I install Transmission BitTorrent client? I came across something called **patch** that i think provides Transmission function for the Buildroot busybox

http://buildroot-busybox.2317881.n4.nabble.com/PATCH-introducing-transmission-bittorrent-client-td7898.html

Is this the thing that does the thing? If so, how to go forward?

```
# uname -a
Linux Mammoth 3.2.0 #1 Tue Sep 8 14:42:47 CST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 5):

You're confusing many things here. First "Buildroot Linaro" doesn't mean anything. Buildroot (http://buildroot.org) is an open-source project that provides an embedded Linux build system, Linaro (http://linaro.org) is a non-profit organization that enhances the support of the ARM architecture in the Linux eco-system. The main interaction between the two is that Buildroot can use a Linaro toolchain as the cross-compiler.

Indeed, there is nothing like "aptitude" on a Buildroot generated system, because we don't support binary packages. See http://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#faq-no-binary-packages for details.

Finally, you're confusing Buildroot and Busybox. Busybox is a userspace application that provides a lightweight implementation of many basic Linux utilities. It is one of the 1600+ userspace packages provided by Buildroot.

Busybox definitely doesn't provide a Bittorent client. However, Buildroot indeed has a package for transmission.

So if you want to move forward, you need to get the source of the Buildroot that WD used to generate the firmware to your device, modify this Buildroot to add transmission, then re-build the filesystem using Buildrot, and finally flash it on your device.

Comment: Yeah I mean what you say. Instead of Buildroot's transmission can't I get this utility from busybox? Or can't I install Transmission `deb` package?

Comment: Well, as Thomas said, busybox does not provide a bittorent application. And a buildroot built rootfs do not support deb-packages. It be best to ask the vendor for the Buildroot tree and configuration, to let you build your own rootfs (with the addition of a bittorrent client).